# How to add a image button for cancel in form MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I try to add a cancel button in MVC form besides submit button which is also image button.
 **The code is** :

```
<input type="image" src="../../Images/SUBMIT_bttn1.gif" alt="Submit" />
<a href='<%= Html.ActionLink("EditPage", "Home")%>'>
<img src="../../Images/Cancel_bttn1.gif" /></a>
```

But it gives **Error** :

```
Server Error in '/' Application. HTTP Error 400 - Bad Request
```

What is the problem?
 Thanks.

Comment: When you click that button, are you sure you are redirected to correct url? can you confirm that your "cancel" functionality is working?

Comment: `<a href='<%= Html.ActionLink("EditPage", "Home")%>'>` is going to generate a hyperlink within a hyperlink. I think you meant Url.Action("EditPage", "Home")

Comment: Cancel is not working and that is why I ask the question. I am not sure whether it is redirected to correct url when cancel button is clicked. It looks like not.

Comment: Assuming `Images` is at the site root, just use `/Images/Cancel_bttn1.gif`, etc. Which version of the MVC binaries are you using?

Comment: check this question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23535704/image-button-in-actionlink-mvc

Comment: I don't use razor and stackoverflow.com/questions/23535704 does not apply. I use MVC4.

Comment: I use MVC4. Thanks, /Images/Cancel_bttn1.gif works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `HTML.ActionLink` will create the `<a>` tag. You need `Url.Action` which just create a link the following should work.

```
<a href='<%= Url.Action("EditPage", "Home")%>'>
    <img src="../../Images/Cancel_bttn1.gif" />
</a>
```

Comment: After change to url.action, I got crashed at it with error, "Insufficient stack to continue executing the program safely. This can happen from having too many functions on the call stack or function on the stack using too much stack space."

Comment: That seems to be a different issue take a look at [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16658803/insufficient-stack-to-continue-executing-the-program-safely-asp-net-mvc-4

Comment: You need hit the tick below the arrows